# Schubert and Grassmann varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schubert-calculus

Can anybody please suggest nice reference which will have lots of examples and counter examples for studying Grassmann varieties in particular Schubert variety?

Answer (score 1):

"3264 & All That: Intersection Theory in Algebraic Geometry" by Eisenbud and Harris is a great reference. A pdf is available online [here](http://scholar.harvard.edu/files/joeharris/files/000-final-3264.pdf).